# Xamarin.Android how to sync lists with other users of my app

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android, synchronization

I have no idea where to start with this. I have a shopping list app that displays items in a recycler view and I want to be able to invite other users of my app (using different devices) to be able to join and modify the shopping list etc.

For example person A creates a shopping list using there device. They then want to share the list in real time with person b who is using the app on a different device. Person B should be able to make changes to the items which are then updates so both devices display the list data in real time.

The user should have the option to invite other people to view and edit the list either by using a linking code or a Qr code for example. Once the other sher enters the linking code they should then be able to view and make edits to the lists.

I have read into Firebase real-time database but not sure if this is it is the right tool to achieve this.

Can anyone advise how I should go about implementing this feature into my app??

Comment: This could be implemented on many different ways, including using the Firebase Realtime Database, and probably in dozens of ways on top of that too. Also consider Firebase Dynamic Links: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links if you want to allow sharing with users who don't have the app installed (yet).

Comment: Can you suggest any other ways to show real-time data between different devices (that's easiest to implement)?

Comment: You can google this question and there are several answer there, Firebase real-time database is a good option.

Comment: I have been googling for an answer wanted people's views on the best approach for this